# Como determinar o caminho de busca dos Controllers e Views?

Tags: c#, rotas, asp.net-core

Estou estudando ASP.NET Core MVC em um macOS.

Quando crio um novo projeto, o IDE automaticamente seta minhas Views em uma pasta chamada "Home". Se eu alterar o nome dessa pasta ou mudar as Views de pasta recebo uma mensagem de erro ao executar o projeto:

> "InvalidOperationException: The view 'Index' was not found. The following locations were searched:"

Abri todos os arquivos para ver se algum deles setava o caminho das Views porém não obtive sucesso.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O nome da sua controller por exemplo `HomeController` por lei vai buscar tudo dentro da pasta Home.

A action dentro dela exemplo a `public IActionResult Index` vai procurar dentro da pasta Home o arquivo `Index.cshtml`. Isso é lei.

Isso no ASP.NET Core: para renomear as rotas no campo da URL você deve ir no arquivo `Startup.cs` na `public void Configure` e fazer o seguinte:

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Nome que vai ser chamado na url",
                template: "{controller=Sua-Controller}/{action=Sua-Action}/{Seu-ID-se-houver?}");
        });
```

Pode procurar por mais em: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing

Comment: Felipe, muito obrigado pela força amigo. Não consigo testar agora, mas já marquei como respondida.

Answer (score 1):

No arquivo `Startup.cs` deve ter um método chamado `Configure`. Lá você achará as rotas configuradas, e uma delas é algo para o controlador `Home`, que não existe mais. Altere para o controlador que você criou e reinicie o servidor.

```
routes.MapRoute(
              name: "SomeDescriptiveName",                      
              template: "AnotherNameThatPointsToHome/{action=Index}/{id?}",
              defaults: new { controller = "Home"} 
              );
```

- [StackOverflow: Change Controller Route in ASP.NET Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45806238/change-controller-route-in-asp-net-core)
- [Microsoft Docs: Routing to Controller Actions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing)

Comment: vnbrs, muito obrigado pela ajuda meu bom.